# How to change a Fusion Table layer query based on user input and button?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Google provides a great example of updating a Fusion Table layer on a map here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/change_query

User input is captured like this in the HTML:

```
    <select id="delivery">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
```

The query is then updated like this in the javascript:

```
function updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn) {
    var delivery = document.getElementById('delivery').value;
    if (delivery) {
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: locationColumn,
          from: tableId,
          where: "delivery = '" + delivery + "'"
        }
      });
    } else {
      layer.setOptions({
        query: {
          select: locationColumn,
          from: tableId
        }
      });
    }
```

As you can see on the link above, the query and map layer updates immediately on change.  Instead of updating immediately on change, I would like to have the user select a value in the delivery field, and then update the query on button click:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Update Map">
```

Can anyone provide me with an example or modify the updateMap function to use the button click to prompt the change?

I tried something like this but it did NOT work:

```
var delivery = document.getElementById('button').click();
    if (delivery) { ...
```

Thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: Here is [an example that geocodes an address on a button click then does a query based on the result](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_zipcode_map.html), [another](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_circle_geocode.html), [another](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_circle_geocode_gviz.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great example from Google that answers my original question.  Here is an example that shows a click event to update a Fusion Table layer query:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

The map updates immediately because there is an event associated to the select element in the sample:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delivery'),
        'change', function() {
          updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn);
    });
```

The above code associates an event - On 'change' of the selected value, execute 'updateMap'.

You need to remove this event and associate an event to your button 'click'.

Example:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('<Your Button ID>'),
            'click', function() {
              updateMap(layer, tableId, locationColumn);
        });
```

Having said that, your technique of attaching the event is incorrect. If you are using Javascript, you need to attach the event and add an event listener. If you are using jQuery, you can use 'bind'/'on' functions to attach events.

Comment: Isn't the .addDomListener my event listener?  Shouldn't listen for a button click from the HTML button, much like in the example where it was listening for a change to a field?     I'm not sure what else to add the javascript?  FYI I'm not using jQuery.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is your event listener; however, you would need to associate to an element to listen to. You need to associate the event listener to your button as the example I gave in the above answer - <Your Button ID>.

Comment: Your answer below is exactly what I was telling you - add an event to the button. In Google's example, the button is 'go' and in the code I provided it would be <'Your Button ID'>